# Android set android:targetClass and android:targetPackage programmatically

Tags: android

How do I set these two xml properties programmatically, when creating an intent:

```
android:targetPackage="com.example.prefs"
android:targetClass="com.example.prefs.SettingsActivity"
```

How would this look in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.example.prefs", "com.example.prefs.SettingsActivity");
```

[Link to setClassName here for more info.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClassName%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Can I do         intent.setClassName(getActivity().getPackageName(), getActivity().getPackageName()+"."+MainActivity.class.getSimpleName());?

Comment: The package name of the class is not always the package name of the app.  You need the package name of the app for an intent to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not good to hard code the package name as changing the package name will break the code . If you are creating  the intent in `FirstActivity.java` and trying to launch `SecondActivity.java` , then you can try this -

```
new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
```

This will not require you to mention package name.